# Is Arabic the language of Jinn?

Tags: arabic, jinn

As there seems many similarities in the life of Humans and Jinn, so I was wondering if Arabic is their language or they use diverse languages (according to their areas ...)? Or even they have their specific language?

Note: I'd be grateful if answer the query by submitting Quranic verses or hadiths.

Answer (score 5):

There are many Quranic verses and Ahadith that talk about "jinns", but none of them speaks about their languages, but from some Quranic verses we can deduct that they can speak and understand the human language

```
قل أوحي إلي أنه استمع نفر من الجن فقالوا إنا سمعنا قرآنا عجبا
```

Verse 1 from Surat "Al-JINN "

> Say (O Muhammad SAWW!): It has been revealed to me that a company of Jinns listened (to the Qur'an). They said, 'We have really heard a wonderful Recital!'

So we can deduct that they can hear the human talking.

```
 قال عفريت من الجن أنا آتيك به قبل أن تقوم من مقامك وإني عليه لقوي أمين
```

Verse 39 from Surat " AN-NAML "

> Said an 'Ifrit, of the Jinns: "I will bring it to thee before thou
>   rise from thy council: indeed I have full strength for the purpose,
>   and may be trusted."

In this Surah, the story of the prophet "Suliman" with the Jinn, and in this verse the Jinn speaks with the prophet "Suliman", so we can deduct either that the Jinn can speaks the human language or the prophet "Suliman" understood the Jinn's language .

So we can deduct that some Jinn can understand at least ARABIC language.

*If you are familiar with ARABIC language I can suggest some good references.*

Comment: on the whole, your presented response looks appropriate, especially pointing out Quranic verse. God bless you.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal you'r right that not justify that all of them understood arabic, I did revise the answer, but the clear meaning of the 1st verse, is that the jinn heard and understood arabic, but we cant say for sure that they speak arabic

Comment: Yes thats right. Jazakallh

Comment: Did Sulayman speak Arabic?

Comment: Prophet Sulayman could speak with many different things, including Ant's,Mountains,Animals,Jinns; are we to think that these different subjects can speak Arabic too?

Answer (score 2):

Bismillah,

In addition to what @Billydan provided in his answer regarding the Arabic Language, I would like to add, ***based on my own experience***, that the **Jinns speak different languages just like us human**.

I've mentioned in one of my comments on this site before that I had done **Ruqyah** to a friend of mine who was possessed by multiple Jinns. Some of them spoke and understood English, I spoke with them directly in that language, and some of them spoke and understood Arabic.

Now, the reference that I could think of is a verse in Surat Al-jinn ([#11](http://quran.com/72/11))

[image]

These **divided/different ways** are belief (Muslim or Mushrik), religion, sects, languages, etc.

Comment: Yes you are right, jinns are not supposed to understand arabic BY DEFAULT, they speak different languages. And there is no evidence that they all understand arabic

Comment: Uh, yea, might be both of you are tight, namely: @Atata, and DEAR Zia Ul Rehman Mughal. Jazakomollah Khaira./ On the whole, helpful answer. Well done mate.

Answer (score -5):

the real language of jins is PUSHTO .
Afghan was the son of Hazrat Suleiman A.S  and he requested Hazrat Suleiman A.S to teach him jins language and then he learned PUSHTO .
Afghanistan is a country, having national language PUSHTO and has been named after Afghan who was son of Hazrat Suleiman A.S

Comment: You need to provide references or citations to support your answer.

Comment: Yes, as @Ahmed mention, you should add related reference(s) to your answer.